# Cpp server, UDP socket for each client

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, client-server

When I'm trying to bind a UDP socket on a specific ip (other than 127.0.0.1/INADDR_LOOPBACK or 0.0.0.0/INADDR_ANY) it fails.

I need to have a dedicated UDP socket for each client (point to point connection).

If I don't bind the socket and use sendto and recvfrom function, the data never arrives.

Any obvious solution ?

Comment: You might get a more feedback if you provide the error code that indicates the failure.  Even better, provide a very short snippet of code that demonstrates the failure.  The post as it stands now is rather light on information.

Comment: I think you're looking for the connect() method. Otherwise I don't know why you think you need a UDP socket per client.

Comment: Actualy it's more a theoretical miss understanding from me about udp usage. But duskwff gave me all I needed to know for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind UDP sockets to nonlocal addresses -- binding a UDP socket to an address means that you want packets that are directed *to* that address, not ones that are being sent *from* that address. You'll need to figure out some way to share a single socket across all clients.